# How to make Tile-line?

Tags: c#, java, drawing, 2d

I have 2 tiles, for example. Here is the matrix:

```
0,0,0,0,2
0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0
```

How I can automatically make a line from 1 one to point 2?

Final result will be something like that:

```
0,0,0,1,2
0,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)